# adding a row to CSV file - TypeError: must be str, not tuple

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Trying to add a row to my CSV file in the format; "name, value".
Here is the CSV file:

```
Japanese Yen,169.948
US Dollar,1.67
Pound Sterling,1
Euro,5.5
```

Here is the part of code which is reponsible for adding a row to the CSV file:

```
def add():         
    addCurrency = input("What currency would you like to add: ")
    newRt = float(input("Please enter the new exchange rate from Pound Sterling: "))
    adding = str(addCurrency), str(newRt)
    file = open('exchangeRate.csv', 'a')
    file.write(adding)
```

Comment: this produces a tuple `adding = str(addCurrency), str(newRt)` I think you want `adding = str(addCurrency) + str(newRt)`

Comment: the problem with this is that i did not get it in the format "name, Value" it was in the format "nameValue" which is not usefull for other parts of the program. Also do i still need to cast it to a string?

Comment: In that case just do `adding = str(addCurrency) + ',' + str(newRt)` If this works I will post as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, do some testing before asking. Before `file.write(adding)` you could have put a `print(adding)` of `print(adding.__repr__())` to see what is Pythons problem with your `adding` instance. You would have seen it is like `('Euro', '5.5')` which is a tuple. True if Python complains it needs a string instead of a tuple you passed there a tuple. First, don't convert to float the `newRt` input since you need it as a string either. What you need here is `adding = ','.join((addCurrency, newRt)) + '\n'` or `adding = '{},{}\n'.format(addCurrency, newRt)` or `adding = addCurrency + ',' + newRt + '\n'`. Try to figure out simple problems like this one before questioning SO. Read the tutorial of the documentation.

Comment: this error was then recieved "adding = ','.join((addCurrency, newRt))
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found" do i need to cast adding to string?

Comment: do not worry i solved the problem, it needed to be casted to a string

Comment: Hah, I didn't worried! All methods are fine which I suggested to make your adding value a string which is fine to append to the CSV. I've even edited them to contain the necessary newline character at the end. Good luck with your currency porgram!